# Getting a Refund From Bitdefender

Tags: bitdefender

I accidentally purchased two licenses for Bitdefender using their online store (which avangate operates).

I immediately realised what happened and asked for a refund. There was a quick response from Avangate but their response was to ask Bitdefender for permission. This was on the 15th of May and I haven't heard anything. I've now sent follow up emails to Bitdefender and Avangate (on the 20th) and there's been no response.

How do I get a refund on the license?

Comment: The only thing you can really do is continuously pester Customer Services until they respond

Comment: I don't know who did the downvote, but I'll counter it

Comment: I did something similar last year. After an "are you sure?" initial response, to which I said 'yes', they refunded me within the week.

Comment: @jcuenod Questions about getting refunds from software vendors is outside the scope of this website IMO.

Comment: @Ramhound I beg to differ: http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @jcuenod - I disagree.  I am also not alone in the thought.  I basically see this as a question how to navigate Bitdefender's website and thus fits within the "and it is not about websites or ..."

Comment: If you had a real problem with the software then this *could* be on topic, but your problem is with their customer service department, not the software itself. Navigating their website is also off topic here and customer support issues would not be on topic for webapps either.

Comment: May as well delete then. I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call them. Near the bottom of [this page](http://www.bitdefender.com/support/internet-security-2015/purchase-orders.html) there is a phone option. They have phone numbers for many support centers around the world.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I used the live chat option rather than phoning. I haven't got it sorted yet but progress has been made.

Comment: Actually, I did manage to get a refund in the end but it took a long time and a lot of back and forth email wise. Thanks.